# Call a Stored Procedure inside EXIT Handler in Teradata

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I have created a stored procedure `GRANT_TO_ARCUSER_DUMP()` to grant `DUMP` access on new databases and users to role `ARCUSER_role`.

Inside my stored procedure, I have called two procedures:

1. `PDYNAMIC_SQL` (execution procedure): this procedure executes the SQL statements
2. `XSP_UDMSG` (output procedure): this is stored procedure which invokes a user defined function for output

I have declared an `EXIT` handler inside which I am capturing the Error text and then passing that error text as input parameter for output procedure `XSP_UDMSG`.
But it's not working. Please help me to understand how to call stored procedure inside EXIT handler.

```
Replace PROCEDURE CWPROCS.GRANT_TO_ARCUSER_DUMP()
MainSP: BEGIN
DECLARE V_SQL_STMT   VARCHAR(5000) default '';
DECLARE SQLSTR  VARCHAR(200) ;
DECLARE LV_SQLCODE INTEGER ;
DECLARE LV_ERR_MSG  VARCHAR (2000) DEFAULT '';


--Exit handler when error is encountered                               
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
  SET LV_SQLCODE = SQLCODE;
  SELECT  ' GRANT FAILED - ERROR: ' || ERRORTEXT  
  INTO LV_ERR_MSG FROM DBC.ERRORMSGS
  WHERE ERRORCODE = LV_SQLCODE;
  call CWPROCS.XSP_UDMSG(:LV_ERR_MSG);
  END;                                            

 FOR c1 as a2 CURSOR FOR
 SELECT 'GRANT  DUMP  ' || 'ON ' || TRIM ( DATABASENAME ) || ' TO 
 ARCUSER_ROLE;' AS Statements FROM dbc.databasesv 
 WHERE databasename NOT IN 
 ( SELECT databasename FROM dbc.allrolerightsv WHERE rolename = 
 'ARCUSER_ROLE' ) 
 AND DATABASENAME NOT IN ( 'ALL' , 'DBC' , 'DEFAULT' , 'PUBLIC' , 'EXTUSER' 
 , 'TD_FNSYSLIB' ) 
 DO

 SET V_SQL_STMT = c1.Statements ;

 CALL SYSDBA.PDYNAMIC_SQL(:V_SQL_STMT) ; --Stored Procedure which executes 
 the SQL statements 

 SET V_SQL_STMT = '';

 END FOR;

 IF V_SQL_STMT ='' THEN

 SET SQLSTR ='Grant completed Successfully ';

 CALL CWPROCS.XSP_UDMSG(:SQLSTR) ; 
 END IF;
 END MainSP;
```

Comment: What does *it's not working* mean?

Comment: The stored Procedure needs to give Output "Grant Failed : Error MSg". But I am getting Error from default SQLA  error messaging .

Comment: This might be caused by an error within the Handler, e.g. the `call CWPROCS.XSP_UDMSG`. Btw, you can get the actual error message without dbc.errormsgs using `GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 LV_ERR_MSG = Message_Text;`.